# How to send HTTP/1.0 request via urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2

Seems that urllib2 sends HTTP/1.1 request by default?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use HTTP 1.0 over HTTP 1.1?

Comment: I am also curious why the need for HTTP 1.0

Comment: I am writing a test script for one of my stupid homework, which only uses HTTP 1.0. (the test script is not part of the homework)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

urllib2 uses httplib under the hood to make the connection. You can change it to http 1.0 as shown below. I've included my apache servers access log to show how the http connection have change to 1.0

**code**

```
import urllib2, httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'
print urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost/').read()
```

**access.log**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2012:09:10:27 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2012:09:16:32 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 454 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
```

Comment: I finally figured out by defining my own handler, but your solution is much simpler, thanks :)

Comment: for python 3 users, httplib is replaced by http.client and all the rest is still the same as Marwan's wonderful solution.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid monkey-patching `httplib` (global change), you could subclass `HTTPConnection` and define your own http handler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
    from httplib import HTTPConnection
    from urllib2 import HTTPHandler, build_opener
except ImportError: # Python 3
    from http.client import HTTPConnection
    from urllib.request import HTTPHandler, build_opener

class HTTP10Connection(HTTPConnection):
    _http_vsn = 10
    _http_vsn_str = "HTTP/1.0" 

class HTTP10Handler(HTTPHandler):
    def http_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(HTTP10Connection, req)

opener = build_opener(HTTP10Handler)
print(opener.open('http://stackoverflow.com/q/13656757').read()[:100])
```