# How should I send HTTP request with custom method in python

Tags: python, curl

I need to send HTTP request with custom method to a custom server. I've been googling about executing curl command in python, and mostly I've found:

> **Don't do that!**

I need to execute the following curl command:

```
curl -X MUX -i -H "Connection-Service: API" -H "Service-Address: API" http://172.16.117.40
```

I've been trying with requests library in python with no luck.

Comment: python requests allows custom verbs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-verbs What have you tried & what errors are you seeing?

Comment: I tried this `r = requests.request('MUX', 'http://172.16.117.40', headers={'Connection-Service': 'API', 'Service-Address': 'API'})` and I don't get any answer - in fact, it looks like it hangs somewhere.

Comment: After I've set logging, I get these two messages:
`INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 172.16.117.40
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"MUX / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
`
When running curl I can see the difference in HTTP version - curl sends HTTP/1.0 request (even if I try to specify HTTP/1.1 version with `--http1.1` flag).

Comment: it appears python requests does not support HTTP/1.0 You may have seen [SO How to send HTTP/1.0 request via urllib2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656757/how-to-send-http-1-0-request-via-urllib2)... Maybe there's a similar hack to urllib3 as used by requests, or don't use requests: use urllib2 and httplib directly.

Answer (score 2):

I constructed this solution from various stackoverflow answers:

```
import httplib, urllib2

httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(self.url)
request.add_header('Connection-Service', 'API')
request.add_header('Service-Address', 'API')
request.get_method = lambda: 'MUX'
url = opener.open(request)
url.info().getheader('API')
```

It works as curl command posted in the question and I don't need to mess with the actual command.