# I want to make an HTTP PUT request using Python 2.5.3

Tags: python, python-2.5

I have to use Python 2.5.3. This would be easy if I was using Python 3 request library, but sadly I am locked into Python 2.5.3 for work.

I need to make a 'PUT' request to a RESTful api to get a 204 response back.

I tried using `urllib2` but I don't get the right response that I need

```py
import urllib2

url='http://some_ulr.com'

try:
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'

    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError , e:
    print e.code
    print e.read()
```

I keep getting a 505 as the response.

Comment: 505 is [HTTP Version Not Supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/505). What version(s) of HTTP does the server support? Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/13656757/3001761?

Comment: From what I have been told we are using HTTP 1.1 and I am still having trouble after looking at the link you sent me to.